# weight layout recalculated when I use gone/visible

Tags: android

I have a bottom navigation view and I want to hide it then show it when a specific fragment appear.

The problem is that when I use Gone and or Visible, the view get recalculated then it takes a while to change the fragment and it mess up the top navigation bar since it change height due to the recalculation.

What kind of layout should I use to avoid the recalculation ?

Here is the axml :

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/internal_main_layout"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minHeight="100dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <MyApp.Droid.Views.TopNavigation
        android:id="@+id/internal_top_navbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </MyApp.Droid.Views.TopNavigation >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"/>

    <Myapp.Droid.Views.BottomNavigation
        android:id="@+id/internal_bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </Myapp.Droid.Views.BottomNavigation >
  </LinearLayout>
```

Is there another way to be responsive and avoid recalculation for the rendering ?

Comment: Does it really take ages to redraw the fragment? Also would invisible work better as that wouldn’t adjust the height

Comment: @Brandon with the actual design asked by the customer I cannot just use invisible since it won't fit for their request. But yes, It takes almost half a second to change the fragment then hide the bottom navigation bar.

Comment: Possibly change to a specific height? Say 150dp for top and bottom, and if necessary multiple layouts for different screen sizes, that should resolve the stretching happening going from 1/8/1 to 1/8